# how to call a json request with parameter in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this web service

```
public string LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter(string fromDate, string toDate)
```

and I am calling it like this:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter
```

I need to call it with the parameters

#### it is get webservice

Comment: The name of the method, `LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter`, suggest that it is declared using `[HttpGet]`. In any case you should add the data parameter to your ajax request to send parameters.

Comment: Please look at the relevant [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) before asking questions like this.
The `data` parameter is what you need to pass arguments in your url.

Comment: But if that is an old Asp.Net web service it will need the soap-envelope as well doesn't it?

Comment: @Esa The cryptic "it is get webservice" on the bottom suggests that it is REST, not SOAP.

Comment: @EricHerlitz no it is declared like this `[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]` . is that ok ?

Comment: That would be the same as HttpGet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:4025/...eFilt "         ,
    data: {parameter1: "value", parameter2: "value2"},
    success:function(){}
   });
```

Or event with `$.getJSON`

```
 $.getJSON('url',{parameter1: "value", parameter2: "value2"}).done(function(result){
     //---success
  }).fail(function(e,x,t){
     //----there have been an error
  });
```

EDITS: that `.fail` can be replaced by `.error`

Comment: why there is a `'` before the `$.getJson` ?

Comment: before the `.done` shoule it be `}` instead of `)` ?

Comment: when i execute the getjson now, i got this error `System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: fromDate. at ` . I check the url in the chrome debugging (f12). i got that the url contains `data` world before the fromdate and toDate parameters. why please?

Comment: because of `$.getJSON('url',{parameter1: "value", parameter2: "value2"})` remove `{data:{...}}` please read my last edits

Comment: last question please, should I pass any parameter to the success function in order to read the response inside that function ?

Comment: Yeah `$.getJSON('url',{parameter1: "value", parameter2: "value2"}).done(function(result){
     //---success
  }).fail(function(e,x,t){
     //----there have been an error
  });`

Comment: the web service is executed perfectly, but the `done` function is never exectue, i put `alert` inside it and never fired. why? maybe it is `success` instead of `done` ?

Comment: The function is `done` and I have verified well. So, what you need to do is to Make sure the service returns a json content, not a json string. If needed, set `content-type="text/json"`

Comment: you the one man, it returns string in json format. i will read how to make it json . thanks a lot

Comment: where to set that content type?

Comment: inside your service of course! I mean your service must be able to render a json content! Not essentially a json string. In addition, I'd advice you to add `.error(function(){alert('error');})` in order to see if your url is running an exception or not

Answer (score 1):

Set `type` to `GET` and pass the parameters to `$.ajax`:

```
  $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {parameter1: "value", parameter2: "value2"}
    });
```

Comment: would like to mention that the default type is `GET`. One can or not set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify parameters directly in the url itself

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter?parameter1=" + parameter1.value + '&parameter2=' + parameter2.value ,
        success: function (statusData) {
        },
        error: function () {
        },

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

make the back end method static

```
public static string LoadTotalCallsPerCampignByRangeFilter(string fromDate, string toDate)
```

Comment: please explain better